# NameError: uninitialized constant Smtpapi

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

I am tyring to push my code to Heroku and the build is failing with

```
 NameError: uninitialized constant Smtpapi
    /tmp/build_0ce2a697c4ef6c16626b01b82d9463f3/app/helpers/my_mailer_header.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    /tmp/build_0ce2a697c4ef6c16626b01b82d9463f3/lib/api_v1/users.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
    /tmp/build_0ce2a697c4ef6c16626b01b82d9463f3/lib/api_v1/mymedical.rb:3:in `<class:Mymedical>'
    /tmp/build_0ce2a697c4ef6c16626b01b82d9463f3/lib/api_v1/mymedical.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    /tmp/build_0ce2a697c4ef6c16626b01b82d9463f3/config/routes.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    /tmp/build_0ce2a697c4ef6c16626b01b82d9463f3/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/railties-4.2.11/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:40:in `block in load_paths'
```

I update my Gemfile from Ruby 2.3 to 2.4 and now I am getting this error? Cannot find a solution.

This seems to be the code that is causing the issue.

```
class MyMailerHeader < Smtpapi::Header
```

Does Smtpapi not exist in Ruby 2.4.2?

The Smtpapi is part of Send-Grid gem and some other gem.

```
    sendgrid-ruby (1.1.6)
      faraday (~> 0.9)
      mimemagic
      smtpapi (~> 0.1)
    smtpapi (0.1.0)
```

Comment: What is `Smtpapi`? Where is it coming from? Is it a gem you are using?

Comment: It is part of send-grid   sendgrid-ruby (1.1.6)
      faraday (~> 0.9)
      mimemagic
      smtpapi (~> 0.1)
    smtpapi (0.1.0)

Answer (score 6):

`sendgrid-ruby` depends on `smtpapi` only in version 1.x, later versions including current 5.3.0 do not.

Since this error came along with ruby update - it may be due to gems update. This should have been prevented by `Gemfile.lock`, but if Gemfile contains any mentions of windows (`mswin`, `mingw` etc.) Heroku will ignore it.

The gem itself has not been updated for 4 years now, because sendgrid rewrote `sendgrid-ruby`.
Best option is to follow them and update your code too.
But for app to run before you do that - you can explicitly lock version of sendgrid-ruby: `gem 'sendgrid-ruby', '~>1.1.6'`